# What is the recommended approach to solve outlook addin hanging?

Tags: debugging, vsto, debug-symbols, sysinternals

I am having an outlook addin which is fairly stable and has been used for years. On a citrix machine environment, the addin is causing outlook to hang if it is left open. Logs are not helping much. How can I approach the problem if I can do the native debugging?

Answer (score 0):

Outlook can hang for many reasons. Since Outlook is COM-based, it uses [STA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680112%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which will cause the main UI thread to hang while it waits for a long-running operation to complete (*network call, disk read/write, etc.*).

You will need to review the source code to review what behaviors the component is performing when it hangs. Inserting trace statements ([`Trace.TraceInformation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yacbe11f.aspx)) may also help if you can repeat the hangup. Start with the event `ThisAddIn.ThisAddIn_Startup` to see the entry point to the AddIn. [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647) is a great utility to view the Trace output of your plugin while it's running.

If COM resources are not being cleanup up properly ([`Marshal.ReleaseComObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject.aspx)) - over time the memory consumption will grow which will start making the application sluggish - although it shouldn't cause it to freeze/hang.

Your best bet is understanding the behavior of the plugin to see what **triggers** the hang.